# How to speed up file writing process for big file?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The following code takes a randomized number of lines from a big text file, and split the original big file into two parts. It is very very slow, in the last 'for' loop, writing texts into two files. Is there a way to make it much faster by using multiprocessing module? I am new to this.

```py
with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f, \
    open('split1.txt', 'w') as a, \
    open('split2.txt', 'w') as b:

    all_lines = f.readlines()
    size = len(all_lines)
    print("total size: ", str(size))
    line_numbers = []

    for i in range(size):
        line_numbers.append(i)

    random_sample_line_numbers = shuffle_list(line_numbers, 30000)
    print('Random sample size: ', str(len(random_sample_line_numbers)))
    for i in range(size):
        print(i)
        if i in random_sample_line_numbers:
            b.write(all_lines[i])
        else:
            a.write(all_lines[i])

    print("Randomize done!")
```

EDIT：

```
def shuffle_list(l, n):
    if n>=len(l):
        raise ValueError("Invalid randomized number. Out of list index boundary")
    shuffle(l)
    return l[:n]
```

This **takes hours** to split a file with around 20-million lines. The total size of the file is 2.6G.

Comment: What python version are you using?

Comment: Did you write `shuffle_list` yourself, or is that a builtin? If you wrote it, can you describe what it does or post the code here

Comment: Also how big is the file? Total size not number of lines

Comment: short answer: yes, it is possible to speed up this a lot. Is it important to have exactly 30K records in b or approximate number will also work?

Comment: The `i in random_sample_line_numbers` test would be much faster if you made that variable a set instead of a list.  I don't know how much of your total time is being taken by that test, however.

Comment: @jasonharper even though this would be an improvement, it is still a very suboptimal setup

Comment: @shuffle_list: There no built-in named `shuffle_list`.

Comment: All， shuffle_list is my implemented, please see above edition!

Comment: OK. Time spent on this file from hours to about 1 minutes, by wrapping up random_sample_line_numbers into a set from a list. that's good enough!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to read the entire input file into memory. All you *really* need is to know the number of lines. Let's assume you already know that, and call it `n`. (If need be, you can compute that in a separate pass of the file). Now, as you read through the input, you can choose which file to write to with a probability related to the number of random lines you've already chosen.

```
import random

with open('bigfile.txt', 'r') as f, \
    open('split1.txt', 'w') as a, \
    open('split2.txt', 'w') as b:

    # Compute number of lines, if necessary
    for size, _ in enumerate(f, start=1):
        pass

    f.seek(0)  # Start over

    for line in f:
        out = random.choices([a, b], [n, size - n])
        if out is a:
            n -= 1
        size -= 1
        out.write(line)
```

You can prove that this gives each line the same probability of being chosen for file `a`. Intuitively, each time you choose a line, the probability of choosing a later line decreases, because there are fewer free "slots" available. At the same time, as you read through the file, the probability increases because there are fewer choices left to fill the remaining slots. In the extreme, you'll stop picking lines when `n` reaches 0, and you'll always pick a line once `n == size`.

If you have even a rough estimate of what `size` should be, you can probably use that rather than reading through the entire file to compute its exact size, without deviating too much from a true uniform distribution.

Comment: two issues: choice is not exactly random (odds depend on the line number), and it is possible to avoid two passes if exact count is not strictly enforced.

Comment: First issue: this is mathematically equivalent to uniformly choosing a fixed-sized subset of lines. Earlier lines have a smaller probability of being chosen than later lines, but that's balance by the fact that later lines have a smaller probability of being *considered*. I address the second issue at the end of the answer.

Comment: Yes. I can get to know the total line number at offline.

Comment: This also looks like a great solution for even bigger file!

Comment: @chepner I was wrong. I misread the condition and was trying to solve a slightly different problem.